# Python: Get unique labelnumbers in a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array. Each 2D slice has labelnumbers which could have numbers between 1 and 1800. Now I want to check If some of the labelnumbers only occur once along the z axis. So my idea was to loop over the 3d array and use numpy.unique. But I wonder If there is a smarter way to get thos unique labelnumbers..

**UPDATED**

Here is a approach of me, but I think there must be a faster way

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
array = np.array([[[0,0,1],[1,2,4],[4,4,4]],[[5,5,1],[5,5,1],[4,4,4]],[[0,0,1],[2,2,4],[4,4,4]]])
uniqueNumbers=[]
for x in range(len(array)):
    uniqueNumbers.extend(np.unique(array[x]).tolist())
cnt = Counter(uniqueNumbers)
ultimateUnique=([k for k, v in cnt.items() if v <= 1])
print(ultimateUnique)
```

**output**:

[5]

So in this case only the label 5 is occuring in slice 2 and should be recognized.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: Demonstrate the `dumb` idea first, and then we can help replicate it in a better way - if possible.

Comment: @Divakar Updated the question

Comment: @hpaulj Updated the question